# Callback recursion in Java

Tags: java, asynchronous, recursion

I have method `save`. It saves entity using service which returns me `com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture<Void>`. In case of fail I want to repeat save. I have next code for it:

```
public void save(Entity entity) {
    ListenableFuture<Void> result = service.save(entity);
    Futures.addCallback(result, new FutureCallback<Result>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Result callbackResult)
        {
            //do nothing
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable throwable)
        {
            //some actions
            save(entity);
        }
    });
}
```

But code above can be cause of `StackOverflowException`. If future will be done before `addCallback` then it will be recursive call. How can I optimize this code to remove recursion from it?

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace for the SOE? I'd guess it's due to trying again in `onFailure()` which fails because the future is already done and thus tries and fails again etc. You could try and check the actual state of `result` and skip retrying if it looks that all went well nevertheless - alternatively/additionally you could add a maximum number of retries and probably check the reasons as well. There's no sense doing a retry forever especially if it is bound to fail again (e.g. if there is a query error that just doesn't fix itself automagically).

Comment: This is not recursion, this is just a loop that breaks on success.